# Make baseball diamond squares align with equal spacing in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment

I'm trying to make the baseball diamond squares image to represent each base but I can't align them right. I have Snap To Point set but it doesn't snap to the exact points I want. Here is my image and you can see what I mean by the squares not aligning like I want. It's a bit hard to tell but if you look close enough they aren't aligned perfectly and I want the spacing to be equal on both sides.

[image]

I'm new to using Adobe Illustrator so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easier to work with a square before it is rotated.

1. Create a square using the Rectangle Tool (M). Either click on the
   artboard to enter the dimensions or drag-n-draw.
2. Then go to Object -> Transform -> Move. Enter a horizontal distance
   and leave vertical distance at 0.
3. Select both squares and go to Object -> Transform -> Move. Enter a
   vertical distance (same as the horizontal distance in the last step)
   and leave horizontal distance at 0.
4. Select all 4 squares, move your cursor around the corner of the
   bounding box, hold sift and rotate the selected squares. Or go to Object -> Transform -> Rotate and enter 45.

Comment: YES ^ It's usually easiest to work with your artwork oriented perfectly vertical or horizontal, if you can.  Though, the rotation would be 45, if I'm not mistaken, not 90?

Comment: I wish I had read your answer earlier, because I was able to fix it by subtracting the x and y coordinates of a corner from each square so they had the same height and spacing lol. It was tedious but it worked. Your answer it is really good to know for next time!